# Finding and replacing in text file

Tags: python

I have a list of integers that looks like:

i =   [1020 1022 .... ]

I need to open an xml file which is stored as .txt , where each entry includes

```
Settings="Keys1029"/>
```

I need to iterate through the records replacing each the numbers in "Keys1029" with the list entry. so that instead of having:

```
....Settings="Keys1029"/>
....Settings="Keys1029"/>
```

We have:

```
....Settings="Keys1020"/>
....Settings="Keys1022"/>
```

So far I have:

```
out =   [1020 1022 .... ]
text = open('c:\xml1.txt','r')

for item in out:
    text.replace('1029', item)
```

but I'm getting:

```
text.replace('1029', item)
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Could someone advise me on how to fix this?

Thank you,

Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open()` returns a file object you can't use string operations on it, you've to use either `readlines()` or `read()` to get the text from the file object.

```
import os
out =   [1020,1022]
with open('c:\xml1.txt') as f1,open('c:\somefile.txt',"w") as f2:
    #somefile.txt is temporary file
    text = f1.read()
    for item in out:
        text = text.replace("1029",str(item),1)
    f2.write(text)
#rename that temporary file to real file
os.rename('c:\somefile.txt','c:\xml1.txt')
```

Comment: Won't `text = text.replace("1029",str(item))` replace *all* occurrences of `1029`, and therefore won't do anything at all for the remaining numbers in the `out` list?